# how to change the code view into with-select

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I face some difficulties in sql.I check your site and I beleive all you know well sql.Please help me do that cause I didn't manage too . I want to do those two codes WITH...SELECT .First I must erase them and then to do the WITH..SELECT.

code 1 is this :

```
create view Min_Intervals as (
    select i.reg,min(whn-sdate) as min_i
    from image i join permit p on p.reg = i.reg
    where whn >= sdate
    group by i.reg)
```

code 2 is this:

```
 create view MIN_Intervals_Owners(Owner_ID, Owner_name, Vehicle, MIN_Interval) as (
select k.id,k.name,mi.reg,mi.min_i
from keeper k join vehicle v on v.keeper = k.id join Min_internal mi on mi.reg = v.id)
```

Comment: it's not clear what you want ,please provide sample data and desired output and a clear explanation of your logic

Comment: I want code 1 :create view Min_Intervals as (
    select i.reg,min(whn-sdate) as min_i
    from image i join permit p on p.reg = i.reg
    where whn >= sdate
    group by i.reg)  to do it with...select instead of using create view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to replace the view with a CTE, then use:

```
with Min_Intervals as (
      select i.reg,min(whn-sdate) as min_i
      from image i join
           permit p
           on p.reg = i.reg
      where whn >= sdate
      group by i.reg
     )
select k.id, k.name, mi.reg, mi.min_i
from keeper k join
     vehicle v on
     v.keeper = k.id join
     Min_internal mi 
     on mi.reg = v.id;
```

Comment: yes ,but I want on each of those to do with select.I mean code 1 to have with -select and  the code 2 to have with -select.